# Add value to Firebase (AngularFire)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I try to add new value to database but I do not know how to add without generating the unique key (Highlighted part)

[image]

Here is what I have done so far. Any help would be appreciated!

```
var newRef = GetArrayFactory('users',firebaseUser.uid); //reference to '5QMI4UsOeAXZUxxkuy5jozcrrSK2'
newRef.$add(
    { 'email': email }
).then(function(newRef){
    var id = newRef.key;
    console.log("added record with id " + id);
    list.$indexFor(id); // returns location in the array
});
```

Comment: I checked the docs of the angularfire and I didn't really found what I searched for. In the standard firebase library for angular, there are two functions for saving data. One is push(), which creates this random id, and another is set(), which you can set a value for a specific node. You can specify the whole path and create an id what you want.

Comment: I cannot use either push() or set() (Error not a function). Instead, Im using this document which only has $add .
https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#addnewdata

Comment: I think you need to use [$save](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#saverecordorindex) instead of $add

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work :(

Comment: I talked about the [standard firebase javascript API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) provided by the google, not about the `angularfire` what you are using. In my angular projects I used this API without any problem. [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) is how can you add it.

Comment: Im using AngularFire 

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html